# Append Value to 3D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I iterate over a 3D numpy array and want to append in every step a float value to the array in the 3rd dimension (axis =2).
Something like (I know the code doesn't work as of now, `latIndex, data` and `lonIndex` for simplicity as randoms)

```
import numpy as np
import random

GridData = np.ones((121, 201, 1000)) 
data = np.random.rand(4800, 4800)
for row  in range(4800):
    for column in range(4800):
        latIndex = random.randrange(0, 121, 1)
        lonIndex = random.randrange(0, 201, 1)
        GridData = np.append(GridData[latIndex, lonIndex, :], data[column, row], axis = 2)
```

The 3rd dimension of `GridData` is arbitrary in this example of size 1000.
How can I achieve this?

Addition: 
It might be possible without `np.append` but then I don't know how to do this since the 3rd index is different for every combination of `latIndex` and `lonIndex`.

Comment: Appending is slow. Do you know the end shape of `GridData` in advance?

Comment: @user228395 I know the first two dimensions (121 and 201) and the third is approximately 950 - 1000 (varies probably).

Comment: @user228395 I cannot compute the exact size in advance. I could just make it big enough, so that I probably don't exceed the indices.

Comment: Are you trying to append ```data``` values to ```GridData```, so that you end up with an array of shape ```(121, 201, 1002)``` (in this example)? Or do you want to append ```GridData``` to ```data``` to end with an array of shape ```(4800, 4800, 1000)```?

Comment: @nicholashz ```data``` values to ```GridData``` exactly.

Comment: Ok. In your example you'd be appending more than once to each array in ```axis=2```, since you'd append 4800 x 4800 times to ```GridData``` which only has 121 x 201 elements. So in the end you want to have arrays of different sizes? Or will they all be of shape ```(1002, )``` somehow?

Comment: @nicholashz In the end I want one 3D-array (```GridData```) which has approximately the same number of elements as ```data``` (missing values can be filled with NA or zero). The problem is that some rows of ```GridData``` will have 900 elements or 950 and so on (in the 3rd dimension). And that every combination of ```latIndex``` and ```lonIndex``` has a different 3rd index (see above). Otherwise I would know how to do this.

Comment: I think it's best not to use numpy arrays if you need to change the shape a lot. Every time you append, insert, etc. to a numpy array, it is not done in-place. So a new array is allocated in memory every time and the data is copied over, which is really slow and expensive. You could allocate a new array yourself and then fill it, but you need to know the worst-case size of the third axis in advance.

Comment: @nicholashz Ok but I am not sure how I can implement a individuell index for every combination of ```latIndex ``` & ```lonIndex```. Let's say I have  ```latIndex = 30```&```lonIndex = 21``` and already 20 elements in the 3rd dimension. Then the index switches to ```latIndex = 31```&```lonIndex = 22``` and the index should start at 0 but it can happen that in the next step it is ```latIndex = 30```&```lonIndex = 21```  again and then it should be index 21. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allocate extra space for your array `grid_data`, fill it with the NaN, and keep track of the next index to be filled in another array while iterating through and filling with values from `data`. If you completely fill the third dimension for some `lat_idx, lon_idx` with non-NaN values, then you just allocate more space. Since appending is expensive with `numpy`, it's best that this extra space is pretty large so you only do it once or twice (below I allocate twice the original space).

Once the array is filled, you can remove the added space that was unused with `numpy.isnan()`. This solution does what you want but is very slow (for the example values you gave it took about two minutes), but the slow execution comes from iterating rather than the `numpy` operations.

Here's the code:

```py
import random
import numpy as np

grid_data = np.ones(shape=(121, 201, 1000))
data = np.random.rand(4800, 4800)

# keep track of next index to fill for all the arrays in axis 2
next_to_fill = np.full(shape=(grid_data.shape[0], grid_data.shape[1]),
                       fill_value=grid_data.shape[2],
                       dtype=np.int32)

# allocate more space
double_shape = (grid_data.shape[0], grid_data.shape[1], grid_data.shape[2] * 2)
extra_space = np.full(shape=double_shape, fill_value=np.nan)
grid_data = np.append(grid_data, extra_space, axis=2)

for row in range(4800):
    for col in range(4800):
        lat_idx = random.randint(0, 120)
        lon_idx = random.randint(0, 200)

        # allocate more space if needed
        if next_to_fill[lat_idx, lon_idx] >= grid_data.shape[2]:
            grid_data = np.append(grid_data, extra_space, axis=2)

        grid_data[lat_idx, lon_idx, next_to_fill[lat_idx, lon_idx]] = data[row,
                                                                           col]
        next_to_fill[lat_idx, lon_idx] += 1

# remove unnecessary nans that were appended
not_all_nan_idxs = ~np.isnan(grid_data).all(axis=(0, 1))
grid_data = grid_data[:, :, not_all_nan_idxs]
```

Comment: Thanks! I think ```fill_value``` should be 0, not 1000 like in your code.

Comment: You mean when you create ```next_to_fill```? It should be ```1000```, so that you start at the end of your array. If you start at ```0``` you will overwrite your previous data in ```grid_data```.